"Trigger happy" closing of a question with no feedback
Within like 20 minutes of my question being asked, my question is closed.
Wouldn't it have been more appropriate to put this question on hold, if the feeling by evaluators was that it is too specifically asking for parts. What I am asking for, generation of nonuniform radiation over a very small volume, is fairly unconventional, and is not like I'm just asking for someone to find me a resistor on minicircuits -- and blanket closing my question and forcing me to appeal without any feedback is difficult for me to see as healthy behavior.
I get that I can edit the question, and then wait for it to be reopened, but this typically procedure takes a long time -- and forcing me to wait that long before getting feedback seems extremely unnecessary.

"Putting a question on hold" isn't a thing on Stack Exchange. It used to be, with a question only being closed after it had been on hold for seven days, but mechanically there was no difference between "on hold" and "closed" IIRC, and the "on hold" status was removed years ago.

For a forum that supports discussion and product recommendations I suggest that you look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements and problems as possible.
Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively).
Some members of this group are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Your question was closed by three users; two of them voted to close as not suitable for "seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them" and one voted to close as "needs details or clarity". The latter did post a comment asking for clarification moments before casting the actual vote to close. The other two close voters did not leave a comment, but the close vote reason they gave is self-explanatory -- in order words, the close reason is the feedback. It's simply not true that your question was closed with "no feedback".
In my judgment, all three close votes were justified: your question was missing some details which made it unclear, and the first version of your question (which was the version that was closed) did seem to be asking for a specific product in that it contained this text:

Does anyone know of a simple way that this can be done? Ideally by purchasing something off-the-shelf equipment, if possible.

I understand it can be frustrating to have your question closed, but the point of closure is to make sure the question is in good condition before anyone spends time attempting to write an answer. While your question might seem clear to you since you know exactly what your problem is, it's easy to forget to include critical details which make your question unanswerable unless they are stated in your post.

I think asking for clarification would have been a much more reasonable course of action. Also, I don't know for sure but I don't think the comments came until after it was closed and I edited it, but I don't know that history.
Also, I am actually in agreeement that this particularly situation worked out fine. And I might have jumped the gun a bit, in this particular case.
But often what has happened to me is that I'm stuck in question-limbo with a closed, downvoted question that prevents me from getting any answers.

Overall though, just keep in mind that this question went from -1 votes and being closed, so becoming +4 upvotes after some edits.
It would be much more appropirate in my opinion for users to communicate what is unclear before slamming the big close button without feedback.

@StevenSagona As a moderator I can see the full timeline of the post, including deleted comments, and there is a comment by one of the close voters posted just before the vote to close.

@StevenSagona The fact that your question went from negative score and closed to positive score (and HNQ) after some edits just proves that the system worked well. The post was closed so that no one would try to answer what was initially an unclear shopping question until it could be edited / improved. I would agree that close voters should generally not vote to close without some feedback, but you did receive appropriate feedback in this case.

@StevenSagona Why get offended at closing? You read the message of closure at the top of the post and take corrective action and we reopen the question so we can bring you a repository of good questions. SE is good because of the moderation system, that's what brings people here day after day.

@VoltageSpike, that's a strange and emotive comment, there's no sign of StevenSagona getting 'offended' or anything like. Rather than remaining in confusion, OP simply used the site processes to post a reasonable and well-explained enquiry, after seeing a course of action they didn't understand.

"trigger happy" isn't getting offended? IMO it is

@VoltageSpike, blimey, no, it's not a sign of 'offended', unless one was unrealistically precious and sensitive - OP just used a phrase.
